# Resolving interface that has sub interface using autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

In our  project, the registration of services is like the ff code:

```
builder.RegisterType< Car >().As< IVehicle >().InstancePerDependency();
```

If `Car` has another Interface, how can I change the above code to resolve it?

let's say the relationship is like the ff:

```
Car : ICar, IVehicle
```

Comment: So did my answer help you ?

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
builder.RegisterType<Car>().
     As<IVehicle>().
     As<ICar>().
     SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Hello again, just a follow up question.. 
is your answer also applicable if the relationship 
is like the ff?: 


Car : Vehicle, ICar 


where the definition of Vehicle class is: 
Vehicle : IVehicle 


and the definition of ICar interface is: 
ICar : IVehicle